# How to restrict the number of pods on an EKS managed node

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc, amazon-eks, eksctl

I am managing the infrastructure on AWS using Cloudformation Script. An EKS cluster with managed nodegroups is created and the instance type is m5a.16xlarge(64 cores,256gb ram). Now the maximum number of pods the instance can have is 737 which is based upon max ENIs and number of Ip addresses in the subnetwork. I need to restrict the number of pods on my managed nodegroup such that it does not go beyond a specific custom count.
What should I do to achieve that?

Comment: The max pods k8s actually "supports" is 100 per node. https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/best-practices/cluster-large/

Comment: @jordanm Will this be applicable to EKS as well? Because in my case I have seen the number of pods go up to 120 or even 140 on a specific worker of size(m5a.16xlarge)

Comment: 100 isn't a hard limit, just the highest k8s claims to be able to support.

Comment: Yes, so I need it to be 80. How should I make sure that it is not more than 80?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer to this. We can restrict the number of pods on a specific eks cluster by using Custom AMI's for worker nodes.

Here is the link for creating the custom AMI:

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/eks-custom-linux-ami/

This link provides a way to clone a repository into your local machine, customise it and then create the ami in your aws account. The local machine or any ec2 instance where the repo is being cloned  must be configured with aws cli latest version.

Once the repo is cloned we can edit the configuration of /sampleDir/files/eni-max-pods.txt file which consists of all the supported instances with their max pods value. /sampleDir/ is the directory where we are cloning the repository.

After this we need to run the 'make' command and it will automatically create the custom ami in any given region. We can then use a cloudformation template to launch managed nodes or self managed nodes on eks.

Here is a sample cloudformation template.

**Note: We can use the same CF Template for managed nodegroups by editing the nodegroup section with type: Aws::EKS::Nodegroup**

```
Description: Amazon EKS - Node Group

Metadata:
  "AWS::CloudFormation::Interface":
    ParameterGroups:
      - Label:
          default: EKS Cluster
        Parameters:
          - ClusterName
          - ClusterControlPlaneSecurityGroup
      - Label:
          default: Worker Node Configuration
        Parameters:
          - NodeGroupName
          - NodeAutoScalingGroupMinSize
          - NodeAutoScalingGroupDesiredCapacity
          - NodeAutoScalingGroupMaxSize
          - NodeInstanceType
          - NodeImageIdSSMParam
          - NodeImageId
          - NodeVolumeSize
          - KeyName
          - BootstrapArguments
          - DisableIMDSv1
      - Label:
          default: Worker Network Configuration
        Parameters:
          - VpcId
          - Subnets

Parameters:
  BootstrapArguments:
    Type: String
    Default: ""
    Description: "Arguments to pass to the bootstrap script. See files/bootstrap.sh in https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-eks-ami"

  ClusterControlPlaneSecurityGroup:
    Type: "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup::Id"
    Description: The security group of the cluster control plane.

  ClusterName:
    Type: String
    Description: The cluster name provided when the cluster was created. If it is incorrect, nodes will not be able to join the cluster.

  KeyName:
    Type: "AWS::EC2::KeyPair::KeyName"
    Description: The EC2 Key Pair to allow SSH access to the instances

  NodeAutoScalingGroupDesiredCapacity:
    Type: Number
    Default: 3
    Description: Desired capacity of Node Group ASG.

  NodeAutoScalingGroupMaxSize:
    Type: Number
    Default: 4
    Description: Maximum size of Node Group ASG. Set to at least 1 greater than NodeAutoScalingGroupDesiredCapacity.

  NodeAutoScalingGroupMinSize:
    Type: Number
    Default: 1
    Description: Minimum size of Node Group ASG.

  NodeGroupName:
    Type: String
    Description: Unique identifier for the Node Group.

  NodeImageId:
    Type: String
    Default: ""
    Description: (Optional) Specify your own custom image ID. This value overrides any AWS Systems Manager Parameter Store value specified above.

  NodeImageIdSSMParam:
    Type: "AWS::SSM::Parameter::Value<AWS::EC2::Image::Id>"
    Default: /aws/service/eks/optimized-ami/1.17/amazon-linux-2/recommended/image_id
    Description: AWS Systems Manager Parameter Store parameter of the AMI ID for the worker node instances. Change this value to match the version of Kubernetes you are using.

  DisableIMDSv1:
    Type: String
    Default: "false"
    AllowedValues:
      - "false"
      - "true"

  NodeInstanceType:
    Type: String
    Default: t3.medium
    AllowedValues:
      - a1.2xlarge
      - a1.4xlarge
      - a1.large
      - a1.medium
      - a1.metal
      - a1.xlarge
      - c1.medium
      - c1.xlarge
      - c3.2xlarge
      - c3.4xlarge
      - c3.8xlarge
      - c3.large
      - c3.xlarge
      - c4.2xlarge
      - c4.4xlarge
      - c4.8xlarge
      - c4.large
      - c4.xlarge
      - c5.12xlarge
      - c5.18xlarge
      - c5.24xlarge
      - c5.2xlarge
      - c5.4xlarge
      - c5.9xlarge
      - c5.large
      - c5.metal
      - c5.xlarge
      - c5a.12xlarge
      - c5a.16xlarge
      - c5a.24xlarge
      - c5a.2xlarge
      - c5a.4xlarge
      - c5a.8xlarge
      - c5a.large
      - c5a.metal
      - c5a.xlarge
      - c5ad.12xlarge
      - c5ad.16xlarge
      - c5ad.24xlarge
      - c5ad.2xlarge
      - c5ad.4xlarge
      - c5ad.8xlarge
      - c5ad.large
      - c5ad.metal
      - c5ad.xlarge
      - c5d.12xlarge
      - c5d.18xlarge
      - c5d.24xlarge
      - c5d.2xlarge
      - c5d.4xlarge
      - c5d.9xlarge
      - c5d.large
      - c5d.metal
      - c5d.xlarge
      - c5n.18xlarge
      - c5n.2xlarge
      - c5n.4xlarge
      - c5n.9xlarge
      - c5n.large
      - c5n.metal
      - c5n.xlarge
      - c6g.12xlarge
      - c6g.16xlarge
      - c6g.2xlarge
      - c6g.4xlarge
      - c6g.8xlarge
      - c6g.large
      - c6g.medium
      - c6g.metal
      - c6g.xlarge
      - c6gd.12xlarge
      - c6gd.16xlarge
      - c6gd.2xlarge
      - c6gd.4xlarge
      - c6gd.8xlarge
      - c6gd.large
      - c6gd.medium
      - c6gd.metal
      - c6gd.xlarge
      - c6gn.12xlarge
      - c6gn.16xlarge
      - c6gn.2xlarge
      - c6gn.4xlarge
      - c6gn.8xlarge
      - c6gn.large
      - c6gn.medium
      - c6gn.xlarge
      - cc2.8xlarge
      - cr1.8xlarge
      - d2.2xlarge
      - d2.4xlarge
      - d2.8xlarge
      - d2.xlarge
      - d3.2xlarge
      - d3.4xlarge
      - d3.8xlarge
      - d3.xlarge
      - d3en.12xlarge
      - d3en.2xlarge
      - d3en.4xlarge
      - d3en.6xlarge
      - d3en.8xlarge
      - d3en.xlarge
      - f1.16xlarge
      - f1.2xlarge
      - f1.4xlarge
      - g2.2xlarge
      - g2.8xlarge
      - g3.16xlarge
      - g3.4xlarge
      - g3.8xlarge
      - g3s.xlarge
      - g4ad.16xlarge
      - g4ad.4xlarge
      - g4ad.8xlarge
      - g4dn.12xlarge
      - g4dn.16xlarge
      - g4dn.2xlarge
      - g4dn.4xlarge
      - g4dn.8xlarge
      - g4dn.metal
      - g4dn.xlarge
      - h1.16xlarge
      - h1.2xlarge
      - h1.4xlarge
      - h1.8xlarge
      - hs1.8xlarge
      - i2.2xlarge
      - i2.4xlarge
      - i2.8xlarge
      - i2.xlarge
      - i3.16xlarge
      - i3.2xlarge
      - i3.4xlarge
      - i3.8xlarge
      - i3.large
      - i3.metal
      - i3.xlarge
      - i3en.12xlarge
      - i3en.24xlarge
      - i3en.2xlarge
      - i3en.3xlarge
      - i3en.6xlarge
      - i3en.large
      - i3en.metal
      - i3en.xlarge
      - inf1.24xlarge
      - inf1.2xlarge
      - inf1.6xlarge
      - inf1.xlarge
      - m1.large
      - m1.medium
      - m1.small
      - m1.xlarge
      - m2.2xlarge
      - m2.4xlarge
      - m2.xlarge
      - m3.2xlarge
      - m3.large
      - m3.medium
      - m3.xlarge
      - m4.10xlarge
      - m4.16xlarge
      - m4.2xlarge
      - m4.4xlarge
      - m4.large
      - m4.xlarge
      - m5.12xlarge
      - m5.16xlarge
      - m5.24xlarge
      - m5.2xlarge
      - m5.4xlarge
      - m5.8xlarge
      - m5.large
      - m5.metal
      - m5.xlarge
      - m5a.12xlarge
      - m5a.16xlarge
      - m5a.24xlarge
      - m5a.2xlarge
      - m5a.4xlarge
      - m5a.8xlarge
      - m5a.large
      - m5a.xlarge
      - m5ad.12xlarge
      - m5ad.16xlarge
      - m5ad.24xlarge
      - m5ad.2xlarge
      - m5ad.4xlarge
      - m5ad.8xlarge
      - m5ad.large
      - m5ad.xlarge
      - m5d.12xlarge
      - m5d.16xlarge
      - m5d.24xlarge
      - m5d.2xlarge
      - m5d.4xlarge
      - m5d.8xlarge
      - m5d.large
      - m5d.metal
      - m5d.xlarge
      - m5dn.12xlarge
      - m5dn.16xlarge
      - m5dn.24xlarge
      - m5dn.2xlarge
      - m5dn.4xlarge
      - m5dn.8xlarge
      - m5dn.large
      - m5dn.xlarge
      - m5n.12xlarge
      - m5n.16xlarge
      - m5n.24xlarge
      - m5n.2xlarge
      - m5n.4xlarge
      - m5n.8xlarge
      - m5n.large
      - m5n.xlarge
      - m5zn.12xlarge
      - m5zn.2xlarge
      - m5zn.3xlarge
      - m5zn.6xlarge
      - m5zn.large
      - m5zn.metal
      - m5zn.xlarge
      - m6g.12xlarge
      - m6g.16xlarge
      - m6g.2xlarge
      - m6g.4xlarge
      - m6g.8xlarge
      - m6g.large
      - m6g.medium
      - m6g.metal
      - m6g.xlarge
      - m6gd.12xlarge
      - m6gd.16xlarge
      - m6gd.2xlarge
      - m6gd.4xlarge
      - m6gd.8xlarge
      - m6gd.large
      - m6gd.medium
      - m6gd.metal
      - m6gd.xlarge
      - mac1.metal
      - p2.16xlarge
      - p2.8xlarge
      - p2.xlarge
      - p3.16xlarge
      - p3.2xlarge
      - p3.8xlarge
      - p3dn.24xlarge
      - p4d.24xlarge
      - r3.2xlarge
      - r3.4xlarge
      - r3.8xlarge
      - r3.large
      - r3.xlarge
      - r4.16xlarge
      - r4.2xlarge
      - r4.4xlarge
      - r4.8xlarge
      - r4.large
      - r4.xlarge
      - r5.12xlarge
      - r5.16xlarge
      - r5.24xlarge
      - r5.2xlarge
      - r5.4xlarge
      - r5.8xlarge
      - r5.large
      - r5.metal
      - r5.xlarge
      - r5a.12xlarge
      - r5a.16xlarge
      - r5a.24xlarge
      - r5a.2xlarge
      - r5a.4xlarge
      - r5a.8xlarge
      - r5a.large
      - r5a.xlarge
      - r5ad.12xlarge
      - r5ad.16xlarge
      - r5ad.24xlarge
      - r5ad.2xlarge
      - r5ad.4xlarge
      - r5ad.8xlarge
      - r5ad.large
      - r5ad.xlarge
      - r5b.12xlarge
      - r5b.16xlarge
      - r5b.24xlarge
      - r5b.2xlarge
      - r5b.4xlarge
      - r5b.8xlarge
      - r5b.large
      - r5b.metal
      - r5b.xlarge
      - r5d.12xlarge
      - r5d.16xlarge
      - r5d.24xlarge
      - r5d.2xlarge
      - r5d.4xlarge
      - r5d.8xlarge
      - r5d.large
      - r5d.metal
      - r5d.xlarge
      - r5dn.12xlarge
      - r5dn.16xlarge
      - r5dn.24xlarge
      - r5dn.2xlarge
      - r5dn.4xlarge
      - r5dn.8xlarge
      - r5dn.large
      - r5dn.xlarge
      - r5n.12xlarge
      - r5n.16xlarge
      - r5n.24xlarge
      - r5n.2xlarge
      - r5n.4xlarge
      - r5n.8xlarge
      - r5n.large
      - r5n.xlarge
      - r6g.12xlarge
      - r6g.16xlarge
      - r6g.2xlarge
      - r6g.4xlarge
      - r6g.8xlarge
      - r6g.large
      - r6g.medium
      - r6g.metal
      - r6g.xlarge
      - r6gd.12xlarge
      - r6gd.16xlarge
      - r6gd.2xlarge
      - r6gd.4xlarge
      - r6gd.8xlarge
      - r6gd.large
      - r6gd.medium
      - r6gd.metal
      - r6gd.xlarge
      - t1.micro
      - t2.2xlarge
      - t2.large
      - t2.medium
      - t2.micro
      - t2.nano
      - t2.small
      - t2.xlarge
      - t3.2xlarge
      - t3.large
      - t3.medium
      - t3.micro
      - t3.nano
      - t3.small
      - t3.xlarge
      - t3a.2xlarge
      - t3a.large
      - t3a.medium
      - t3a.micro
      - t3a.nano
      - t3a.small
      - t3a.xlarge
      - t4g.2xlarge
      - t4g.large
      - t4g.medium
      - t4g.micro
      - t4g.nano
      - t4g.small
      - t4g.xlarge
      - u-12tb1.metal
      - u-18tb1.metal
      - u-24tb1.metal
      - u-6tb1.metal
      - u-9tb1.metal
      - x1.16xlarge
      - x1.32xlarge
      - x1e.16xlarge
      - x1e.2xlarge
      - x1e.32xlarge
      - x1e.4xlarge
      - x1e.8xlarge
      - x1e.xlarge
      - z1d.12xlarge
      - z1d.2xlarge
      - z1d.3xlarge
      - z1d.6xlarge
      - z1d.large
      - z1d.metal
      - z1d.xlarge
    ConstraintDescription: Must be a valid EC2 instance type
    Description: EC2 instance type for the node instances

  NodeVolumeSize:
    Type: Number
    Default: 20
    Description: Node volume size

  Subnets:
    Type: "List<AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id>"
    Description: The subnets where workers can be created.

  VpcId:
    Type: "AWS::EC2::VPC::Id"
    Description: The VPC of the worker instances

Mappings:
  PartitionMap:
    aws:
      EC2ServicePrincipal: "ec2.amazonaws.com"
    aws-us-gov:
      EC2ServicePrincipal: "ec2.amazonaws.com"
    aws-cn:
      EC2ServicePrincipal: "ec2.amazonaws.com.cn"
    aws-iso:
      EC2ServicePrincipal: "ec2.c2s.ic.gov"
    aws-iso-b:
      EC2ServicePrincipal: "ec2.sc2s.sgov.gov"

Conditions:
  HasNodeImageId: !Not
    - "Fn::Equals":
      - !Ref NodeImageId
      - ""

  IMDSv1Disabled:
    "Fn::Equals":
      - !Ref DisableIMDSv1
      - "true"

Resources:
  NodeInstanceRole:
    Type: "AWS::IAM::Role"
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - !FindInMap [PartitionMap, !Ref "AWS::Partition", EC2ServicePrincipal]
            Action:
              - "sts:AssumeRole"
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - !Sub "arn:${AWS::Partition}:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEKSWorkerNodePolicy"
        - !Sub "arn:${AWS::Partition}:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEKS_CNI_Policy"
        - !Sub "arn:${AWS::Partition}:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryReadOnly"
      Path: /

  NodeInstanceProfile:
    Type: "AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile"
    Properties:
      Path: /
      Roles:
        - !Ref NodeInstanceRole

  NodeSecurityGroup:
    Type: "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup"
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: Security group for all nodes in the cluster
      Tags:
        - Key: !Sub kubernetes.io/cluster/${ClusterName}
          Value: owned
      VpcId: !Ref VpcId

  NodeSecurityGroupIngress:
    Type: "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress"
    DependsOn: NodeSecurityGroup
    Properties:
      Description: Allow node to communicate with each other
      FromPort: 0
      GroupId: !Ref NodeSecurityGroup
      IpProtocol: "-1"
      SourceSecurityGroupId: !Ref NodeSecurityGroup
      ToPort: 65535

  ClusterControlPlaneSecurityGroupIngress:
    Type: "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress"
    DependsOn: NodeSecurityGroup
    Properties:
      Description: Allow pods to communicate with the cluster API Server
      FromPort: 443
      GroupId: !Ref ClusterControlPlaneSecurityGroup
      IpProtocol: tcp
      SourceSecurityGroupId: !Ref NodeSecurityGroup
      ToPort: 443

  ControlPlaneEgressToNodeSecurityGroup:
    Type: "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupEgress"
    DependsOn: NodeSecurityGroup
    Properties:
      Description: Allow the cluster control plane to communicate with worker Kubelet and pods
      DestinationSecurityGroupId: !Ref NodeSecurityGroup
      FromPort: 1025
      GroupId: !Ref ClusterControlPlaneSecurityGroup
      IpProtocol: tcp
      ToPort: 65535

  ControlPlaneEgressToNodeSecurityGroupOn443:
    Type: "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupEgress"
    DependsOn: NodeSecurityGroup
    Properties:
      Description: Allow the cluster control plane to communicate with pods running extension API servers on port 443
      DestinationSecurityGroupId: !Ref NodeSecurityGroup
      FromPort: 443
      GroupId: !Ref ClusterControlPlaneSecurityGroup
      IpProtocol: tcp
      ToPort: 443

  NodeSecurityGroupFromControlPlaneIngress:
    Type: "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress"
    DependsOn: NodeSecurityGroup
    Properties:
      Description: Allow worker Kubelets and pods to receive communication from the cluster control plane
      FromPort: 1025
      GroupId: !Ref NodeSecurityGroup
      IpProtocol: tcp
      SourceSecurityGroupId: !Ref ClusterControlPlaneSecurityGroup
      ToPort: 65535

  NodeSecurityGroupFromControlPlaneOn443Ingress:
    Type: "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress"
    DependsOn: NodeSecurityGroup
    Properties:
      Description: Allow pods running extension API servers on port 443 to receive communication from cluster control plane
      FromPort: 443
      GroupId: !Ref NodeSecurityGroup
      IpProtocol: tcp
      SourceSecurityGroupId: !Ref ClusterControlPlaneSecurityGroup
      ToPort: 443

  NodeLaunchTemplate:
    Type: "AWS::EC2::LaunchTemplate"
    Properties:
      LaunchTemplateData:
        BlockDeviceMappings:
          - DeviceName: /dev/xvda
            Ebs:
              DeleteOnTermination: true
              VolumeSize: !Ref NodeVolumeSize
              VolumeType: gp2
        IamInstanceProfile:
          Arn: !GetAtt NodeInstanceProfile.Arn
        ImageId: !If
          - HasNodeImageId
          - !Ref NodeImageId
          - !Ref NodeImageIdSSMParam
        InstanceType: !Ref NodeInstanceType
        KeyName: !Ref KeyName
        SecurityGroupIds:
        - !Ref NodeSecurityGroup
        UserData: !Base64
          "Fn::Sub": |
            #!/bin/bash
            set -o xtrace
            /etc/eks/bootstrap.sh ${ClusterName} ${BootstrapArguments},
            
            /opt/aws/bin/cfn-signal --exit-code $? \
                     --stack  ${AWS::StackName} \
                     --resource NodeGroup  \
                     --region ${AWS::Region}
        MetadataOptions:
          HttpPutResponseHopLimit : 2
          HttpEndpoint: enabled
          HttpTokens: !If
            - IMDSv1Disabled
            - required
            - optional

  NodeGroup:
    Type: "AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup"
    Properties:
      DesiredCapacity: !Ref NodeAutoScalingGroupDesiredCapacity
      LaunchTemplate:
        LaunchTemplateId: !Ref NodeLaunchTemplate
        Version: !GetAtt NodeLaunchTemplate.LatestVersionNumber
      MaxSize: !Ref NodeAutoScalingGroupMaxSize
      MinSize: !Ref NodeAutoScalingGroupMinSize
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          PropagateAtLaunch: true
          Value: !Sub ${ClusterName}-${NodeGroupName}-Node
        - Key: !Sub kubernetes.io/cluster/${ClusterName}
          PropagateAtLaunch: true
          Value: owned
      VPCZoneIdentifier: !Ref Subnets
    UpdatePolicy:
      AutoScalingRollingUpdate:
        MaxBatchSize: 1
        MinInstancesInService: !Ref NodeAutoScalingGroupDesiredCapacity
        PauseTime: PT5M

Outputs:
  NodeInstanceRole:
    Description: The node instance role
    Value: !GetAtt NodeInstanceRole.Arn

  NodeSecurityGroup:
    Description: The security group for the node group
    Value: !Ref NodeSecurityGroup

  NodeAutoScalingGroup:
    Description: The autoscaling group
    Value: !Ref NodeGroup
```